# Trouble with Kali Linux in vmware: "Connection Failed: Activation of network connection failed"

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I just put a Kali Linux VM on VMware Workstation Pro 15, but it keeps giving me the error: `Connection Failed: Activation of network connection failed`. In the VM's network adapter is set to NAT right now but I have also tried bridged. It seems to not be getting dhcp but I am not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Under Vmware settings for that particular VM. Add an additional network adapter. Once the VM updates, it should show a connection. If it doesn't, add a new connection profile in "Wired Settings". Once it's connected, you can remove the adapter that isn't working.